# Task inside Cloud Functions Authentication trigger needs async?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

#### Statement

First of all let me just say firebase team is the best.

#### Code

```
    //Firebase Cloud Functions
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');    
    // Firebase Admin SDK
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(); //initialize the admin sdk
    //UUID
    const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

    exports.setupProfile= functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
         const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
         const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the us
         const pid = uuidv1(); // public id

         //**************** 
         //create a set of items visible to others
         return admin.database().ref('/users-public/' + pid).push({"displayName": displayName,"profile-pic-path":""});

         //user's private information
         return admin.database().ref('/users-private/' + user.uid).push({"displayName": displayName, "pid": pid,"email":email,"dob": "","address": "","age": "","zip-code":""});
         //****************         

    });
```

#### What I want to accomplish/understand

I am working on a logic to create user profile scaffolding/default settings when a user signs up for the first time.

#### What I understand so far

Authentication triggers, like all other background functions, are asynchronous meaning if person A and person B signs up at the same time and the function above gets triggered for both then neither person A nor person B has to wait for the other person's 'setupProfile' function to complete. Essentially two different threads.

#### Questions

1. Do the lines between the asterisks have to be inside async() method
   for this entire process to be truly asynchronous or would it mean that putting it inside async() will essentially spawn another thread from the triggered thread?
2. Should I not bother with async() because I should think of each trigger as its own thread therefore any tasks within that trigger would be part of that single thread(initial trigger) and there is no added benefit to spawning another thread. I should simply return a promise and call it a day.

Please let me know if I need to clear things up.
-LK

#### Working code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(); //initialize the admi sdk
exports.setupProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user, context) => {
    return Promise.all([
        admin.database().ref("/users-public/" + user.uid).set({ "displayName": ""}),
        admin.database().ref('/users-private/' + user.uid).set({ "displayName": "", "email": user.email, "phone": "", "dob": "", "address": "", "age": "", "zip-code": ""})
    ]).then((results)=> {
        console.log("New user: " + user.uid);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as shown, will not run as expected, because the first return will prevent the second return from ever executing.

If you have two items of asynchronous work that don't need to be performed in order, you should just instead collect all the promises into an array and use `Promise.all()` on that array.

Another thing to clarify - Cloud Functions does not deal with the concept of threads in JavaScript.  There is just asynchronous work that executes per function, and each function invocation runs in its own server instance, isolated from all other function invocations.  You may want to [watch my video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCpKxpIMg6o) that explains this in more detail.

Comment: Hey @doug-stevenson - thanks for the quick reply!

**facepalm** you're right the second return will never see the light of day.

Great suggestion. I'll get to work on that once I get home.

Comment: Ok no threads but am I right to assume that if two users sign up at the same then that function will get triggered simultaneously for those two users? 

I've watched all your videos and they are great learning sources. These must be new, can't wait to watch them but man between work and personal projects I'm coding in like 7 to 8 languages and solving 5 or 6 times more problems. It's hard to keep track of all.

I'll share my code once its done. Thanks again!

Comment: You should assume that two function invocations might run at the same time.  No guarantees on that, just make the assumption.

Comment: hey @doug-stevenson I have 5 different background functions and they are all utilizing the admin.database().ref() method. Would it make sense to create a global variable `const database = admin.database();` at the top of the page? Will I see a performance increase, like how heavy is calling the `admin.database.ref()` every time I point to a database reference?

Comment: It's not very expensive.